# Different definitions of total curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm looking at this paper 'Boundary conditions at a liquid-vapor interface' by Prosperetti 1979 and on the second page this definition is given for the total curvature:

The total curvature $\mathscr{C}$ of the interface at a point $P$ is defined by

$\mathscr{C} = \frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{R'}$

where $R$ and $R'$ are the radii of curvature of the sections of the interface with any two planes orthogonal to each other and to the interface at $P$.

I'm not too familiar with differential geometry but this seems pretty different from the usual definition of total curvature and it's also not the same as Gaussian curvature which would be the product instead of the sum. Is there another better-known name for this curvature term?

Edit: interface here refers to a surface. The context being the 'interface' between a liquid and a vapor.

Comment: This looks like 2 times the mean curvature, I don't know if that is a convention in fluids.

Comment: Ah okay great, that is exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: @mxnoqwerty but shouldn't that be the case only in the directions of maximum curvature? How is that number C independent of the pair of planes chosen?

Comment: @Compacto I admit I don't quite understand the definition in the paper (what is the "interface at $P$" ?), but it does seem to be [usual convention in fluid mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature#Mean_curvature_in_fluid_mechanics) to drop the factor $2$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch ah the interface is a surface. The context being the 'interface' between a liquid and vapor, I've edited the qn.

Comment: I think that C is not well defined. It should say that R and R' are the maximum and minimum radii. Their reciprocals are called *principal curvatures*.

Comment: I was wondering that too, but I saw somewhere that the sum of normal curvatures for any pair of orthogonal directions at a point P on a surface S is constant, does that apply here?

Comment: Yes, cyan_ogen, that is correct. It is immediate from Euler’s formula. I was about to correct @Compacto.

Comment: Oh, I didn't remember that